# Smoke shows on render, Fire doesn't

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

Good day! I am having a problem wherein fire does not render. I followed a [smoke and fire simulation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs&t=107s). Followed everything in his tutorial. However, the fire in my scene does not render at all. I wanted it to look like rocket thrusters. As of now, this is what I currently have for my Smoke Domain material.

[image: Nodes Expanded][image: Nodes]

I temporarily set the smoke to 0 because it may be blocking the flame. I've provided the screenshots where the smoke is enabled and disabled. (Forgive the quality of the rendered images, I lowered down the samples to quickly render the image.

[image: No Smoke][image: With Smoke]

And for my scene, this is what it looks like.

[image: Scene]

I am rendering it using GPU compute. If there's anything missing in the  current scene setup, just ask for it and i'll provide the necessary requirements. I tried searching for solutions but nothing worked out for me. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute nodes are case-sensitive, if you change "Flame" to "flame", that should correct the issue!

Comment: It did fix the problem. Not really a pro with blender. Didn't knew they were case-sensitive. Thanks a lot!