# I cant render Fire

Tags: rendering, fire

I have fire in the viewport, but when i enter rendered view or just render the image i only get stuff that looks like dust. [image: Rendered image]

[image: unrendered]

[image]

Comment: add a picture of the material nodes for the domain.

Comment: ok added it hope its useful info

Comment: Attributes are case-sensitive. I think you need to use ‘flame’ in place of ‘Flame’. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116632/29586

Comment: ok thanks it was the capitalization that was causing the problem